# what changes do i need to make to this code so that it does not show real time changes from the database..but only loads new data when refreshed.?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I need the onRefresh function here to refresh the brewList when i pull. I tried a few things but its not working and only refreshes after hot reload. 
   so when i pull down to refresh it should reflect any changes that were made in the firestore.

```
 class BrewList extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _BrewListState createState() => _BrewListState();
    }

    class _BrewListState extends State<BrewList> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        final brews = Provider.of<List<Brew>>(context) ?? [];

        return RefreshIndicator(
            onRefresh: refresh,
           ListView.builder(
          itemCount: brews.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return BrewTile(brew: brews[index]);
          },
         ),
        );
      }
    }






  // get brews future
  Future<List<Brew>> get brews async {
   QuerySnapshot snapshot =  await brewCollection.getDocuments();
   return _brewListFromSnapshot(snapshot);
  }





List<Brew> _brewListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc){
      //print(doc.data);
      return Brew(
        name: doc.data['name'] ?? '',
        strength: doc.data['strength'] ?? 0,
        sugars: doc.data['sugars'] ?? '0'
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing your stream to this and see if this helps

```
 // get brews future
  Future<List<Brew>> get brews async {
   QuerySnapshot snapshot =  await brewCollection.getDocuments();
   return _brewListFromSnapshot(snapshot);
  }
```

and then just call your provider when you want to update. My guess is you are also using a stream somewhere too doesn't seem necessary if you are not actively updating content.

okay I took a look at the github for this project and there are probably other changes you need to make first of now that your not using that stream it doesn't make sense to use a `StreamProvider` change that to a `FutureProvider` setup should be very similar and actually i know it was my orgional suggestion to change the provider to listen false but after looking at your project try changing back. since you do want to make periodic updates

```
Future refreshList() async {
    setState(() {
    brews = Provider.of<List<Brew>>(context) ;
    });
  }
```

Comment: if i do (context, listen: false) then it does not show any brew on the ui

Comment: also please mention the function for refresh indicator ..i tried getting brew list on refresh(), but it doesn't update on simulator until i hot reload..i'll make another question later because it does not let me do it today.

Comment: You still there? Ill save you the trouble of posting another question.

Comment: yes..i'm here..its the same code as above..i've wrapped the listview.builder with a refreshIndicator.. just need the function to refresh the brew list .. i already edited and added the refreshIndicator in the above code.

Comment: yes I had already changed the stream provider to future provider when you told me to change the stream to future..and that is why the brew list loads one time and stops listening to changes in the stream..which is exactly what i want..but i also want to add a rafreshIndicator which will refresh the brewList and show the most recent changes made in firestore..so what's the function to use in the refreshIndicator which will accomplish the same?

Comment: try calling ```brews = Provider.of<List<Brew>>(context)```

Comment: your going to have to change brew from ```final``` to ```List<Brew>```

Comment: still not working..do i need to change anything else?

Comment: hey are you still there?? i can create a new question later if this is all messed up here